# How do I add two icons and multiple actions on a FAB in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, floating-action-button

I want to add two icons on FAB Flutter, one icon will be a map(onPressed show map) and other icon will trigger showBottomModel. A kind of icon switch based floatingActionBar, I don't know if that is possible or please tell me a work around. Thanks.

Comment: Please share some code, what you've tried so far.

Comment: @ibhavikmakwana I've tried expanded FAB but even that can't contain more than one icon or more than one action. So, I am stuck on this for a while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **flutter_speed_dial** package/dependency [here](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_speed_dial) or try below code hope its help to you.

```
   floatingActionButton: Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
    children: [
      FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () => {},
        child: Icon(Icons.person),
      ),
      FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () => {},
        child: Icon(Icons.home),
      ),
    ]
  ),
```

Your result screen -> [image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, I just wanted to ask is it possible to make them as a slider switcher? this works anyway. So, thanks.